# Draw 8 x 15 Rectangle-Grid in C++ with OpenGL - crash down

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, opengl, screen

i want to create 8 x 15 Matrix of Rectangles in C++ with OpenGl.
I first create a Class for just a rectangle. Then i created a class for a row of Rectangles, it contains an Array of 8 Rectangles. Then i created a class for 15 rows (the whole matrix).

I think i have a pointer problem...
This is what i did for testing:

created 1..2 rectangles an drew them - ok
created 1..2 rows and drew them -- ok
created 1 field and drew it -- ok
created 2 matrix-- windows just opend and crashed ...it was white with a error msg xD

So this is my display function... it works for example for 3 rows.
but if i would put in `MatrixRectangles field1(0,0);` and `MatrixRectangles field2(0,0);` and print all out in the display function with void `drawAllRows();` it wouldn't work .

```
void display(void) {
    // glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);
    glEnd();

    row1.drawAllRectangles();
    row2.drawAllRectangles();
    row3.drawAllRectangles();
    glFlush();
}


class RectangleGL {
public:
    RectangleGL();
    RectangleGL(float hoehe, float breite, float startx, float starty);
    virtual ~RectangleGL();
    float getWidth() const;
    float getHight() const;
    void setBreite(float breite);
    void setHight(float hohe);
    void drawRectangle();
    float getStartx() const;
    void setStartx(float startx);
    void printRectangleData();
    void setStarty(float starty);
private:
    float hight;
    float width;
    float startx;
    float starty;
};

#endif /* VIERECKGL_H_
```

```
/*
 * Reihe_ViereckeGL.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 19.10.2019
 *      Author: N1
 */

#include "Reihe_ViereckeGL.h"
rowRectangle::rowRectangle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}
rowRectangle::rowRectangle(float startx,float starty) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        float m = i * 0.1;
        this->rectangles[i] = new RectangleGL(0.1, 0.1, m+startx, starty); // always a new x position , everytime higher...

    }
}

rowRectangle::~rowRectangle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

float rowRectangle::getStarty() const {
    return starty;
}

void rowRectangle::setStarty(float starty) {
    this->starty = starty;
}

void rowRectangle::drawAllRectangles() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        this->rectangles[i]->drawRectangle();
    }
}
```

```
/*
 * Reihe_ViereckeGL.h
 *
 *  Created on: 19.10.2019
 *      Author: N1
 */

#ifndef REIHE_VIERECKEGL_H_
#define REIHE_VIERECKEGL_H_
#include "ViereckGL.h"
class rowRectangle {
public:
    rowRectangle();
    rowRectangle(float startx,float starty);
    virtual ~rowRectangle();
    float getStarty() const;
    void setStarty(float starty);
    void drawAllRectangles();
    RectangleGL* rectangles[8];
private:
    int anzReihe;
    int rowNr;
    float startx; // offset x..
    float starty; // offset... y
};

#endif /* REIHE_VIERECKEGL_H_ */
```

```
/*
 * FeldViereckeGL.h
 *
 *  Created on: 19.10.2019
 *      Author: N1
 */

#ifndef FELDVIERECKEGL_H_
#define FELDVIERECKEGL_H_
#include "Reihe_ViereckeGL.h"
class MatrixRectangles {
public:
    MatrixRectangles(float startx, float starty);
    virtual ~MatrixRectangles();
    rowRectangle *rowRectangles[8];
    void drawAllRows();
};

#endif /* FELDVIERECKEGL_H_ */
```

```
    /*
     * FeldViereckeGL.cpp
     *
     *  Created on: 19.10.2019
     *      Author: N1
     */

    #include "FeldViereckeGL.h"

    MatrixRectangles::MatrixRectangles(float startx, float starty) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            float m = i * 0.1;
            this->rowRectangles[i] = new rowRectangle(startx, m + starty); // everytime a higher position
        }
    }

    MatrixRectangles::~MatrixRectangles() {
        // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    }
    void MatrixRectangles::drawAllRows() {
        // zeichne alle reihen
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            rowRectangles[i]->drawAllRectangles(); // draw all rectangles !
        }
    }
```

i would expect a nice 8 x 15 Rectangle Matrix. But instead the window , which openes crashes down - it gets white - ",,, exe doesnt work anymore"

Comment: what error message? which line of code crashes? What compiler you use?

Comment: hi, i think in the console wasn't a error description, there just came an error window^^ but you are right i should have done it with the Debugger , because it would have gone to the code line were it would crash ! I use Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array of rows has only 8 elements:

```
rowRectangle *rowRectangles[8];
```

However your are iterating though 15 elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    float m = i * 0.1;
    this->rowRectangles[i] = new rowRectangle(startx, m + starty); // everytime a higher position
}
```

That's why it is crashing.

A good practice is defining a constant variable for the number of rows.

```
static constexpr int numRows = 15;
rowRectangle *rowRectangles[numRows];
```

And use `numRows` everywhere instead of `15`. That will prevent bugs in the future. And, when you need to change the number of rows, you only need to do so in one place.

Comment: thank you ! It works now. i am happy. and i am sry, i should have checked my array sizes...(just came from java programming, so it cost a lot of nerves to rethink) yes  i also think it will be better to describe a constant  for my rows and columns and so on :D !